# Gnome doesn't update sound output device properly

Tags: gnome, sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

I run Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome 3.30.1 on an XPS 9370.
If I have music playing (via the built-in speakers) and connect my docking station (a Dell WD15) the music automatically transitions to the speakers connected to the dock (it has a  line-out output). The problem is, that Gnome does not recognize it: Even if Gnome shows the line-out output in the sound devices overview, it still has the internal speakers selected and the multimedia keys still adjust the internal speaker.
[image: Status after connecting]

Has anyone an idea how to fix it?